# submit .py script on Spark without Hadoop installation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following simple wordcount Python script.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

from operator import add
f=sc.textFile("C:/Spark/spark-1.2.0/README.md")
wc=f.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" ")).map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(add)
print wc
wc.saveAsTextFile("wc_out.txt")
```

I am launching this script using this command line:

```
spark-submit "C:/Users/Alexis/Desktop/SparkTest.py"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
15/04/20 18:58:01 WARN Utils: Your hostname, AE-LenovoUltra resolves to a loopba
ck address: 127.0.1.2; using 192.168.1.63 instead (on interface net0)
15/04/20 18:58:01 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another
address
15/04/20 18:58:10 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library fo
r your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/04/20 18:58:11 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoo
p binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Ha
doop binaries.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:293)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:867)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$12.apply(SparkContext.scala:28
0)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$12.apply(SparkContext.scala:28
0)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.sc
ala:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand
.java:79)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alexis/Desktop/SparkTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-1.2.0\python\pyspark\context.py", line 105, in __init__
    conf, jsc)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-1.2.0\python\pyspark\context.py", line 153, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-1.2.0\python\pyspark\context.py", line 201, in _initializ
e_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-1.2.0\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.p
y", line 701, in __call__
  File "C:\Spark\spark-1.2.0\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py",
line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spa
rk.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$12.apply(SparkContext.scala:28
0)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$12.apply(SparkContext.scala:28
0)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.sc
ala:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand
.java:79)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

To a Spark beginner like me, it seems that this is the problem: "ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path". However, the Spark documentation clearly states that a Hadoop installation is not necessary for Spark to run in standalone mode.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The good news is you're not doing anything wrong, and your code will run after the error is mitigated.

Despite the statement that Spark will run on Windows without Hadoop, it still looks for some Hadoop components.  The bug has a JIRA ticket ([SPARK-2356](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2356)), and a patch is available.  As of Spark 1.3.1, the patch hasn't been committed to the main branch yet.

Fortunately, there's a fairly easy work around.

1. Create a bin directory for winutils under your Spark installation directory.  In my case, Spark is installed in D:\Languages\Spark, so I created the following path:  D:\Languages\Spark\winutils\bin
2. Download the winutils.exe from Hortonworks and put it into the bin directory created in the first step.  Download link for Win64:  http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe
3. Create a "HADOOP_HOME" environment variable that points to the winutils directory (not the bin subdirectory).  You can do this in a couple of ways:

   - a. Establish a permanent environment variable via the `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment variables`.  You can create either a user variable or a system variable with the following parameters:

     `Variable Name=HADOOP_HOME
      Variable Value=D:\Languages\Spark\winutils\`
   - b. Set a temporary environment variable inside your command shell
     before executing your script

     `set HADOOP_HOME=d:\\Languages\\Spark\\winutils`
4. Run your code.  It should work without error now.