# Problems loading SparkContext() in Spyder (for Python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spyder

I'm trying to load SparkContext through Spyder. To load Pyspark in Spyder, I send the following command into the Windows command line:

```
spark-submit.cmd C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\Scripts\spyder.py
```

which works and I can import pyspark sucessfully in Spyder. However, whenever I try to create an instance of SparkContext() I get the following error:

```
sc=pyspark.SparkContext()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-e5c2c851d239>", line 1, in <module>
sc=pyspark.SparkContext()

  File "C:\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 113, in __init__
conf, jsc, profiler_cls)

  File "C:\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 165, in _do_init
self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)

  File "C:\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 219, in _initialize_context
return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)

  File "C:\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 701, in __call__
self._fqn)

  File "C:\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
format(target_id, '.', name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1351)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1305)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Can anyone help interpret what `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NullPointerException` means?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. It seems to be that Hadoop looks for files even though they are not there. This link explains how to create a winutils folder, file and HADOOP_HOME variable that got my pyspark running through spyder on win 7:

[submit .py script on Spark without Hadoop installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746395/submit-py-script-on-spark-without-hadoop-installation)